# VS 2010 включение библиотеки

Tags: visual-studio, c++, visual-c++

Целый день мучаюсь,так как в VS 2010 работаю недавно. Необходимо включить в проект стороннюю библиотеку,а никак не пойму что от меня требуется,вот ссылка на всякий случай:
https://github.com/noporpoise/BitArray/tree/15ce22cc58252c400465f1077630084cb954def2

или вот что там написано:

```
Build

To build and run the test code:

make

./bit_array_test

Using bit_array in your code
Add to the top of your code:

#include "bit_array.h"

Add to your compiler arguments

BIT_ARR_PATH=path/to/bit_array/

gcc ... -I$(BIT_ARR_PATH) -L$(BIT_ARR_PATH) -libbitarr

You can then call the following methods:

Constructor - create a new bit array of length nbits

BIT_ARRAY* bit_array_create(bit_index_t nbits);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Просто копируете файл `bit_array.c` и файл `bit_array.h` в каталог своего проекта.
2. Добавляете файл `bit_array.c` к проекту в окне браузера файлов в VS.
3. Пытаетесь скомпилировать, правите возникающие по ходу дела ошибки.

Comment: вот именно что не работает!!! выдает ошибку что отсутствует <inttype.h> я его скачал,он выдает что отсутствует <machine/ansi.h> и его я добавил,а потом вообще ошибок 60 выдает!

Comment: Правильно, а что Вы хотели? Вы же хотите использовать изначально линуксовую программу. Ее нужно адаптировать. Если хотите более конкретно - выкладывайте точные ошибки, которые возникают. Причем без подключения inttype.h и ansi.h, т.к. там могут быть несовместимые с VS2010 определения.

Comment: И вообще какова конечная цель? Если посмотреть внимательно, то можно увидеть, например, [это][1]. Ну, а далее не проблема использовать `boost::dynamic_bitset` или [`CBitArray`][2]

 [1]:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633400/c-c-efficient-bit-array/2633584#2633584
 [2]:http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9034/Bits-Array-Encapsulation

Comment: 1)error C1853: файл предкомпилированного заголовка "Debug\Ex01.pch" создан в предыдущей версии компилятора или предкомпилированный заголовок C++ используется из C (или наоборот) (bitarray.c)

2)IntelliSense: не удается открыть источник файл "inttypes.h" (bitarray.h)
3)IntelliSense: идентификатор "uint64_t" не определен
(bitarray.h)

Comment: Попробуйте вручную создать эти определения или возьмите их из http://msinttypes.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/stdint.h

Касательно C1853 - полная очистка проекта от временных файлов должна помочь. Ну, и можно `bitarray.c` переименовать в `bitarray.cpp`.

Comment: Проблема решена! Огромное спасибо!